# How do you enter an interactive php console with code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an existing code igniter app. If I try to enter a console with `php -a` but none of my code igniter classes are loaded. How do can this be achieved?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Codeigniter loads its dependencies through the `index.php` file. When you go to `http://somesite.com/controller/method` it's really `http://somesite.com/index.php?controller/method` which the library knows to process. This isn't often seen since most people hide the `index.php` with a `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write PHP in the terminal with the CodeIgniter framework loaded, I'm not sure that'll be possible because CodeIgniter includes this line on every file.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

If you want to run some of the code of your project through the terminal, this page may be useful to you.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html

You'll go to your project root, and run something along the lines of the following, replacing `ControllerName` and `MethodName` with whatever the controller or method is.

```
php index.php ControllerName MethodName
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
php -a
php > include('index.php');
php > $CI =& get_instance();
php > var_dump($CI->config->item('language'));
```

That should do it.